# Retrieving values posted using the link

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I am trying to submit a form using a hyperlink and it is not posting values onto the next page.Here is my code form:

```
<?php
$email = array('name'=>'accountno','id'=>'accountno','value'=>set_value('email'));
 ?>    

<form method="post" id = "login_form" action="/salesrep/check" name = "login_form" class="custLogin">
<fieldset style="color: #BD1313; width: 440px;">  <input type="hidden" name="submit_type" id="submit_type" value="account_only">
<br><center><label for="customerNo"><b>Customer No:</b></label>
<?  echo form_input($email);?>
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; <a href="/salesrep/check" class="shopping-icon" onclick="document.login_form.submit()">Submit</a><? echo form_input($button);?>   </center>
   <p>&nbsp;</p>
           </fieldset> 
   </form>
```

The code on the next page looks like this:

```
<?
print_array($_POST);
         die();
 ?>
```

When i use the button here,it posts values to next page successfully.BUT I HAVE not been able to post values using the hyperlink on onclick event. Where i am making mistake??
Why i am getting empty array when i am already  inserting value in the text box.?? Or is there any way i could post values using the link and retrieve them in the next page???

Comment: Where is code of form_input()?

Comment: use print_r($_POST); to print the POST values.

Comment: @YashankitVyas.I am using code igniter form helper.

Comment: Guys.I am getting empty array i.e Array()...Weired!

Answer (score 0):

The *real* problem is that you are trying to use a link plus some JavaScript to submit a form in the first place. Don't do this. Buttons inform users that they will submit the form. They will show up in screen readers when they are in *forms mode* (a link with some JavaScript won't). They "just work".

If you insist on using a link and some JavaScript, then the reason that your code doesn't work is that the JavaScript runs, the form starts to submit, then the link is followed and a GET request is made to the page instead.

Normally you could call [`preventDefault`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault) on the event to stop this, but you are using old style intrinsic event attributes so you need to `return false;` from there instead.

Recommended reading: [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript)